# Extracting array of type double from UDP socket in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matlab, udp

I am just trying to set up a simple connection where I send an array of data over UDP from Matlab to a JavaScript function. I am essentially trying to send an array  `D= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` from Matlab to JS over UDP. However, I seem to only be able to obtain the first value (i.e. 1). I was wondering if someone could just see where I am going wrong? Sorry about the coding here, I am not very used to JS so I am sure there is something basic that I am missing/not understanding here.

On the Matlab side of things I have written a simple script as below. I just run this every time I want to send `D` via UDP, for the JS to detect.

```
    %Create object to send data from
    uSend = udpport("datagram","IPV4","LocalHost","127.0.0.1","LocalPort",3000);
    
    %Data to send
     D = [1:1:10]
    
     %Send Data array D to port 2560
     write(uSend,D,"double","LocalHost",2560);
```

Then on the JavaScript side of things I have a script called `test.js` which is below (the namings of variables probably may cause confusion, but basically I just want it to listen and upon a message over UDP, extract the array). I run it in VSCode using `node test`:

```js
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
var array = [];

server.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
  server.close();
});

//Upon message, do some stuff
server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
    //Attempt to see how big the array is incoming 
    console.log(`message size: ${rinfo.size}`); 

    //loop over size of incoming array 
    for (let index = 0; index < rinfo.size; index++) {
        //write msg index to array (i.e. get D array in JS)
        array[index] = msg[index]
        console.log(` ARRAY VALUE: ${array[index]}`)      
    }

    //announce array obtained
    console.log(`server got: ${msg.readDoubleLE()} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

//announce listening 
server.on('listening', () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});

server.bind(2560,'127.0.0.1');
```

The Output is:

```
server listening 127.0.0.1:2560
message size: 80
 ARRAY VALUE: 0
 ARRAY VALUE: 0
 ARRAY VALUE: 0
 ARRAY VALUE: 0
 ARRAY VALUE: 0
 ARRAY VALUE: 0
 ARRAY VALUE: 240 .... ETC (80 times because of above), values are usually 0, but can be randomly other values... guessing this is just because it's being read wrong. 
....
server got: 1 from 127.0.0.1:3000
```

So this is my current attempt. However, the issue I seem to be facing is regardless of the things I've tried, I only seem to get the first `msg` value (i.e. `msg.readDoubleLE() = 1`), not the whole `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Any thoughts on how to get **all** the values from the `D` array sent from Matlab? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out I forgot about the `JSON.Stringify()` part to this problem, where I had to encode the Matlab output using `jsonencode(D)`. The following therefore works (there's no need for looping etc, send as type `char`):

```
 %Create object to send data from
    uSend = udpport("datagram","IPV4","LocalHost","127.0.0.1","LocalPort",3000);
    
    %Data to send
     D = jsonencode([1:0.1:10])
    
     %Send Data array D to port 2560
     write(uSend,D,"char","LocalHost",2560); //<-- sending it as type 'char'
```

And the JS:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
  server.close();
});

//Upon message, do some stuff
server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {

JSON.stringify
    //announce array obtained
    console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

//announce listening 
server.on('listening', () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});

server.bind(2560,'127.0.0.1');
```

Outputs:
`server got: [1,1.1,1.2,... ]`